# Equality of the transpose of a vector-matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This is a rather trivial question, but in my lecture notes for two vectors $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and a symmetric matrix $C$ I have given
$$
x^TCy=y^TC^Tx
$$
and I do not understand why this is true. I get that
$$
(x^TCy)^T=y^TC^Tx
$$
but why is $(x^TCy)^T=x^TCy=y^TC^Tx$

Comment: Think of a scalar as a ${\tt1}\times{\tt1}$ matrix. Obviously it equals its own transpose since there's only one element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because $C$ is a symmetric matrix (i.e., $C^T = C$)

\begin{align*}
(x^T C y)^T = (y^T C^T (x^T)^T)^T = (y^T C x)^T = x^T C^T (y^T)^T = x^T C y.
\end{align*}